# Alternatives to oDesk.com for contract work? or is oDesk already one of the best?

Tags: freelancing, contract

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find programming work online?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/41981/where-can-i-find-programming-work-online)

I saw oDesk.com being mentioned in one thread here for contract work and freelance work, and the people listed for hire is asking for $15/hour and up to $80 or $100/hour -- of the ones that I saw for development jobs.

I wonder what alternatives there are besides using oDesk.com for programming contract work?  (The fee it charges seems somewhat high, that for $80 / hour that I bill, it charges $8.89 / hour to the employer, so the employer needs to pay $88.89 / hour.)

Comment: Also see: [finding high end software contracting jobs](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/44866/finding-high-end-software-contracting-jobs)

Answer (score 2):

A site that I think is consistently overlooked is [Craigslist](http://www.craigslist.org/) for your area. You'll be able to find work and pay 0 commissions. The other site I've used is [VWorker](http://www.vworker.com/) which was formerly Rent-A-Coder.